# Align A Grid Alongside The Content Of A Scroll Viewer Rather Than The Entire Scroll Viewer Including Scroll Bar?

Tags: wpf, layout

I have the following scenario in XAML:

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="gridLabels" Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Row SharedSizeGroup="FirstRow" MinHeight=24/>
            <Row SharedSizeGroup="SecondRow" MinHeight=24/>
            <Row SharedSizeGroup="ThirdRow" MinHeight24/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">Top Item:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Middle Item:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">Bottom Item:</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrVwItems" Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
        <ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding Bondage}">
            <!--etc-->
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Within the ItemsControl, `DataTemplate`d items have their own grids with SharedSizeGroup set so that the `TextBlock`s etc line up with the TextBlock labels to the far left.

The problem I get is that until the ItemsControl is populated the `SharedSizeGroup`s don't line up and the "Bottom Item:" text falls down level with the horizontal scroll bar of my ScrollViewer.

Is there a simple way I can align the "gridLabels" Grid with the content area of the ScrollViewer rather than the entire ScrollViewer itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted, simply gave the ItemsControl (which is the content of the ScrollViewer) a name and used an ElementName binding to it's ActualHeight from "gridLabels".Height.  Also applied a MinHeight to the ItemsControl.

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="gridLabels" Grid.Column="0" 
        Height={Binding ElementName=myItemsControl, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <Row SharedSizeGroup="FirstRow" MinHeight=24/>
             <Row SharedSizeGroup="SecondRow" MinHeight=24/>
             <Row SharedSizeGroup="ThirdRow" MinHeight24/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">Top Item:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Middle Item:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">Bottom Item:</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrVwItems" Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
        <ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding Bondage}" x:Name="myItemsControl" MinHeight="150">
             <!--etc-->
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```